# How to get node names in my ZooKeeper?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am using HBASE, for which I installed zookeeper. Is there any config file, which has Znode names stored or some command which gives the Znodes names as output ?

Comment: There likely is some configuration for the Zookeeper quorum address. Have you checked the Hbase config files?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your configuration, there seems to be only one node in the quorum (not a quorum technically) and its the local machine. The minimum nodes to maintain a quorum is three.

Answer (score 0):

As Cricket_007 commented, You should see zookeeper quorum info on hbase-site.xml. Looks like you are also looking for what is getting registered and written by Hbase in zookeeper. To get full list and details you can use zk_dump on Hbase shell.

more info on the command

https://learnhbase.wordpress.com/2013/03/02/hbase-shell-commands/

Comment: My zookeeper quorum info in the xml file is :

 `<name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>`
        `<value>localhost</value>`

zk_dump on HBase shell gives output as below.

`hbase(main):002:0> zk_dump`

`ERROR: `

`Here is some help for this command:`
`Dump status of HBase cluster as seen by ZooKeeper.`